# How to solve this for integers $(x^2 + 4)(y^2 + 1) = 8xy$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> How to solve the following equality $$(x^2 + 4)(y^2 + 1) = 8xy$$ for $x,y$ integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$(x^2+4)(y^2+1)-8xy=(xy-2)^2+(x-2y)^2$$

Answer (score 6):

**hint**: $x^2+ 4 \ge 4x, y^2 + 1 \ge 2y$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: solving for $y $ we get

$$y=\dfrac {4 x \pm \sqrt{-( x^2-4)^2}}{4 + x^2}$$

Now check which are the possible values of $x $, considering that we are looking for integer solutions.